# jQuery setting attribute on click does not change the value

Tags: jquery

Well i'm not really a guru in jQuery but i can do some basic stuff. However i can't get the point here. I'm listening to `.btn-delete` `click` event, setting `.btn-danger` `data-route` attribute (in the modal dialog) to the value of `.btn-delete` `data-route` attribute.

Really simple stuff, I know i'm doing it wrong. The **value** of `data-route` for `.btn-danger` **does not change**. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
<!-- modal confirm -->
<div id="modal-delete">
    <a class="btn-danger" data-route="">Confirm</a>
</div>

<!-- delete buttons -->
<a class="bt-delete" data-route="/user/delete/1">Delete</a>
<a class="bt-delete" data-route="/user/delete/2">Delete</a>

<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {

         // Listen to .btn-delete click
         $('.btn-delete').click(function() {

             // Get data-route for the delete button and set it in the modal
             $('#modal-delete .btn-danger')
                 .attr('data-route', $(this).data('ruote'));

             // Do ajax in .btn-danger click event
             $('#modal-delete .btn-danger').click(function() {
                 // data-route does not change
                 console.log($(this).data('route'));
             });
         });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Your code had a bunch of syntax error + selector errors (typo kind).

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/rc6CE/3/)

The DEMO link has the fixed code, please take a look and fix your code accordingly.

1. `$(document).ready(function(` should be `$(document).ready(function() {`
2. `$('.btn-delete').click(function() {` should be `$('.bt-delete').click(function() {`
3. `$(this).data('ruoute')` should be `$(this).data('route')`
4. `$('.btn-delete').click(function() {` should be closed right after setting the data.
5. If `attr` is used then the `console.log` should use `attr` to print the content as `console.log($(this).attr('data-route'));`

**Note:** It is better to use `data` instead of `attr` function. See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/rc6CE/2/) on how to use `data` function.

Comment: Thanks, but i need to set `data-route` for `.btn-danger` IN the modal, taking the value from `data-route` of `.btn-delete`. `.btn-danger` in the confirm button.

Comment: it doesnt work - try and get the console to log "/user/delete/1" and then "/user/delete/2" or the other way around ... `data()` **must** be used

Comment: @ManseUK I can't get the point, data() as far as i understand is used for storing arbitrary data in the NODE, i want to set html5 data-* attribute.

Comment: @ManseUK I agree to the point that using data is recommended, but attr should just work fine. The click function was not closed properly in the DEMO also it was logging the data when setting the attr.

Comment: @SKS i think the point is consistency - using `attr()` might work here but see the [following example where it wont](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7262427/572939)

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#modal-delete .btn-danger').attr('data-route', $(this).data('ruoute'));
```

should be

```
$('#modal-delete .btn-danger').data('data-route', $(this).data('route'));
```

you should always use the `.data()` method (not attr) for getting and setting data associated with a node

There is also another couple of mistakes in your code :

```
$(document).ready(function(
```

should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

and

```
$('.btn-delete').click(function() {
```

should be

```
$('.bt-delete').click(function() {
```

I have removed the `n` to match the HTML

[Works fine for me here](http://jsfiddle.net/eAeLw/)

Comment: have a look at the jsfiddle it works for me - here is an explanation of attr vs data -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr

Comment: Downvote a 3 year old question without any explanation ?!